# Flameshot Screenshot App

Tags: release-juno, software-installation, screenshot

I'm using 5.0 Juno
Linux 4.15.0-64-generic
GTK 3.22.30

I'm installing Flameshot-Screenshot App from this web

https://flameshot.js.org/#/getting-start][1](https://snapcraft.io/install/flameshot-app/elementary)

I like this application because it's very simple and similar to Lighshot on Mac and Windows, which I usually use.
But after installation, the application does not run. The icon bouncing on the Dock then disappears in a few moments.

then I tried another way, via snapcraft.
[Flameshot App Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/install/flameshot-app/elementary)

After the installation process, there is no single icon related to Flameshot in the application list

I beg for help from Elementary developers, a solution how this application can run well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To *really* launch Flameshot after successful installation:

1. Go to `Applications` menu > `Graphics` tab.
2. Locate `Take Graphical Screenshot` flameshot icon.
3. Right-click it and click `Add to Dock` menu item.
4. Right-click this icon in the Dock and click `Keep in Dock` menu item.
5. To launch Flameshot, use this icon. (You can delete 'Launch Flameshot' icon from the Dock.)

Indeed, for some reason, the icon named 'Launch Flameshot' apparently doesn't do anything at all, except for joyful jumping. (At least in v0.5.1 from Ubuntu's depository.) If this behavior is not a bug, then it is definitely a UI design flaw. If you'd like, you can report this issue to the developer @  https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot/issues .